# Accessing data from a List using jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have a bean that has the follwing:

```
public DeptLibraryEntry(int id, String type, String name, String info, Boolean avail){
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.info = info;
    this.avail = avail;
    this.log = new ArrayList<Log>();
}
```

and another bean called Log.It is the following:

```
    public Log(String num, String name, String dateBorrowed, String dateReturned){
    this.num = num;
    this.name = name;
    this.dateBorrowed = dateBorrowed;
    this.dateReturned = dateReturned;
}
```

I want to list the "num","name","dateBorrowed" and "dateReturned" in a JSP.

I am trying the following code in my JSP:

```
<c:forEach items="${entries}" var="entry">
            <tr><td>${entry.Log.num}</td></tr>
</c:forEach>
```

I've tried some variations of this but can't seem to get it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thiss assumes that `entries` is a list/collection of `DeptLibraryEntry`.

Note that `log` (and not `Log`, capitalization is important!) is itself a list of items, so to get the value of each item you have to iterate over it again

```
<c:forEach items="${entries}" var="entry">
  <c:forEach items="${entry.log}" var="logItem">
     <tr><td>${logItem.num}</td></tr>
     ....
  </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Of course, your classes will need to have the appropiate getters to access the properties.

Comment: This works but what its doing now is that it is giving me all the log entries for all Entries. Basically what I need to do is, access a particular Entry(when user selects a particular entry) and look at its log.Thanks!

Comment: Either you add a `c:if` tag in the mix or (prefered), from the servlet you identify the `Log` you want to show and put it in another attribute (and then you no longer would need the `c:forEach`)